# Right click context menu passes only one file as argument

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, contextmenu, regedit

I added a new right-click context menu for my own file type (ftype) under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\ftype\shell` as `do something with ftype` and command as `"path\ftype.bat" "%1"`.
I was able to read command-line arguments from ftype.bat when I right click on a .ftype file.

But am facing issues when I select multiple .ftype files and right click to select my command !
For each selected file, my bat is called like,

```
ftype.bat file1.ftype

ftype.bat file2.ftype
```

Any ways to make it to work the below way?

```
ftype.bat file1.ftype file2.ftype
```

I have tried replacing "%1" in command field with "%*" and with "%1" "%2". But I was able to see spaces being passed to executable !

Note:
Actual regedit entry is a python file and not a bat file as below:

```
<python_exe_path> "<ftype_handler.py>" "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't with a classic static verb using %1. You need to use a [drop handler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183) or [DelegateExecute](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623) shell extension.